# Referencing contents of buffers in external (n)vim commands

Tags: vim, neovim

So far I have only found the `:%! <cmd>` way to pipe the **current** buffer through an external command.
But I am wondering if there is a way to have two or three viewports open and reference their respective buffers, for both input parameters and results of the external command.

Simple example:
I would like to have an open viewport with a file, a viewport with a awk (or jq or anything) script, and a third "result" viewport.
Then I would like to run awk (or jq, etc.) to use the script from the second viewport, running on the file in the first viewport and write the result to the third viewport.

Similar to what vim-jqplay does (unfortunately it is not compatible with nvim)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if there is a way to have two or three viewports open

In Vim slang it's called "windows". Please, don't use inappropriate terms anymore.

> So far I have only found the :%!  way to pipe the current buffer through an external command.

Actually, there are also `:r !{cmd}` (read from cmd, i.e. redirect command's stdout into the buffer) and `:w !{cmd}` (write to cmd, i.e. redirect command's stdin to read from the buffer).

> Then I would like to run awk (or jq, etc.) to use the script from the second viewport, running on the file in the first viewport and write the result to the third viewport.

Well, you realize that you can't have two stdin redirections at the same time, do you? In principle, you can do something like

```
call appendbufline(3, '$', systemlist('gawk -f '..bufname(1), 2))
```

Here 1 is a script buffer number, 2 is datafile bufnr, and 3 is a target bufnr. But note that buffer 1 is passed simply as a filename (no redirection), so it must be saved before the command to run.

But I don't think it's so important to redirect stdin at all, as you can pass datafile name too. So, assuming the target buffer (3) is active, you can do this

```
:r !gawk -f #1 #2
```

Of course, both script (buffer 1) and data (buffer 2) must be saved to disk before running this.

Comment: Pardon my french, I will not use the V word again.

I didn't know about the one stdin redirection, but in this case one would be enough, the file could be referenced as #1 or #2, but I would really like the script to be accesssed directly.
I have used the "save both files first" way before, but always saving the script while trying to get it right is clumsy in my opinion.  I will try your  first solution hopefully it is what I was looking for. I will let you know, thank so you much!

Comment: @JernejFilipčič If it's the script you're redirecting to stdin then I guess it should be `systemlist('gawk -f- '..bufname(2), 1)`

Comment: Matt, sorry for bothering you again. The first appendbufline works, as long as the script is saved on a file, the text can be in a buffer.
But I'm not able to make it work the other way round. In your second reply you just changed the numbers of the buffers) and if I understand correctly, bufname just gives the name of the file corresponding to the buffer, therefore the script still has to be on a file. What is the double dot? Concatenation? How can I make the thing after the -f to be the content of the unsaved buffer?
gawk -f <buffer> file?

Comment: @JernejFilipčič It is `-f-`. See, for example, https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Naming-Standard-Input.html

Comment: silly me, I thought it was a typo.
It works great in gawk! For jq the - as a stdin placeholder didn't work, but I solved it with adding xargs, making  
`:call appendbufline(3,  '$', systemlist('xargs -I % jq % '..bufname(2),  1))`

Problem solved! Thank you so much, Matt!